# How to add a header sub-menu using jQuery on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my page header I have a list of 6 categories and I'd like to add a sub menu for each category, but display it only when category is clicked. (I'd like to use only one handler in my script.js file, not add one for each category in particular. - less code)

Here is my HTML for the list in header:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="menu_item1" class="menu_item">About
    <div id="sub-menu1" class=“sub-menu”></div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu_item2" class="menu_item">Services
    <div id="sub-menu2" class=“sub-menu”></div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu_item3" class="menu_item">Portfolio
    <div id="sub-menu3" class=“sub-menu”></div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu_item4" class="menu_item">Blog
    <div id="sub-menu4" class=“sub-menu”></div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu_item5" class="menu_item">Pictures
    <div id="sub-menu5" class=“sub-menu”></div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu_item6" class="menu_item">Contacts
    <div id="sub-menu6" class=“sub-menu”></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is the SCSS:

```
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 25px;

  .menu_item {
      position:relative;
      font-family: $OpenSansSemibold;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 8px 16px;

    div.sub-menu {
        position:absolute;
        top:40px;
        left: 0;
        width: 200px;
        height: 116px;
        border: 1px solid green;
        background-image: url(../img/popupmenu_03.png);
        display: none;
    }


    &:hover{
        background: #62a29e;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #528b86;
        cursor: pointer;

    }
  }
}
```

And here is what I tried so far, but it doesn't work:

```
$( ".menu_item" ).each(function() {
  $(this).children().find(".sub-menu").toggle();
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the .children() and it should work. .children() accesses direct children already, while .find() will traverse down the DOM tree from that element. So in your code, you were looking for any child (grandchild, etc) of direct children of .menu_item that was clicked. .sub-menu wasn't a child of direct children of .menu_item, but was rather already that element ;) I am using the .find() method here because it'll still work, even if your DOM changes. If you won't change anything in regards to your DOM structure of the menu, you are safe to use $(this).children().toggle();

```
var $subMenus = $(".menu_item").find(".sub-menu");
$(".menu_item").on("click", function() {
  $subMenus.addClass("hidden");
  $(this).find(".sub-menu").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

SCSS:

```
#menu {

  .menu_item {

    div.sub-menu {
        ....
        &.hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @LiviuCraciun, sorry, thought you already had the click listeners and everything and I guess you didn't. Anyway, see the updated code with the updated SCSS as well in the comment ;)

Comment: Thanks for the update. It still doesn't work, I am sure I am missing something in my code, but cannot seem to figure it out..

Comment: @LiviuCraciun, do your divs (the .sub-menu elements) even have any content (I assume you just took it out for the purpose of demonstrating the structure)? Because if they don't have any content, they'll be visible (in HTML sense), but invisible to the naked eye. Or are they meant to provide a reference to somewhere else? Why don't you create a codepen so we can see exactly what you have. I also assume you've included jquery in your html before executing the code and the code is within the document.ready callback?

Comment: Here, I copy pasted 3 files in jsBin, this is what I have locally: a html file, a scss file (I've added only the header.scss for this purpose, the others work just fine) and a script.js. The sub-menu divs have content, they should load and display an image  (I have already positioned them - now for some reason cannot see them displayed anymore). Maybe you can spot the error: https://jsbin.com/lasejajasu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @LiviuCraciun, the jsBin isn't working for me (at all, I see nothing in the output and there are a couple of errors in the console).

Comment: Hello, just to clear out this post, the error was in my html: i used this “ symbol instead of " in .. class="sub-menu". It took me a while to see it..

Comment: @LiviuCraciun, wow, wouldn't have thought to check that heh :) Glad you sorted your HTML out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```js
jQuery( ".menu_item" ).click(function(e) {
  jQuery(this).closest('#menu').find('.sub-menu').filter(':visible').hide(); // hides other open sub-menus
  jQuery(this).find(".sub-menu").toggle(); // opens the clicked item's sub-menu
});
```

```css
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 25px;
}
#menu .menu_item {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'OpenSansSemibold';
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333; /*fff; changed just for display */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
#menu .menu_item div.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 116px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-image: url(../img/popupmenu_03.png);
  display: none;
}
#menu .menu_item:hover {
  background: #62a29e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #528b86;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="menu_item1" class="menu_item">About
    <div id="sub-menu1" class="sub-menu"></div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu_item2" class="menu_item">Services
    <div id="sub-menu2" class="sub-menu"></div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu_item3" class="menu_item">Portfolio
    <div id="sub-menu3" class="sub-menu"></div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu_item4" class="menu_item">Blog
    <div id="sub-menu4" class="sub-menu"></div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu_item5" class="menu_item">Pictures
    <div id="sub-menu5" class="sub-menu"></div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu_item6" class="menu_item">Contacts
    <div id="sub-menu6" class="sub-menu"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```